# Regular Expression for MM/YYYY in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

```
 var filter = new RegExp("(0[123456789]|10|11|12)([/])([1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9])");
```

I want to check given text must be month and year only(mm/yyyy) like 03/2014  .
I tried above code. but it success for 03/2014/02.I want only mm//yyyy format

Please help me, I want only month and year in that format.

Comment: you want mm-yyyy to be the correct format ?

Comment: Your input should be 03/2014

Comment: hm.ya.If i give 03/2014 . It accept.

Comment: What do you want to match and what do you want not to match? [Please take your time to write a complete question](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints) and not use ours for guessing some answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is nearly fine. The only thing you are missing are [anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html). They are important to avoid partial matches, like you see when it (partly) matches on "03/2014/02".

So, add the anchors `^` (start of the string) and `$` (end of the string) to your regex.

```
var filter = new RegExp("^(0[123456789]|10|11|12)([/])([1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9])$");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])/(19|2[0-1])\d{2}$
```

Try This this matches months (1-12) and years 1900-2199.